# Вывод найденного значения из строки при помощи Regex

Tags: powershell

```
$month = "(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)"
$space = "(\040)+"
$day = "([0-9]|[1-3][0-9])"
$year = "[1-2][0-9]{3}"
$time = "[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}"
$regex = $month + $space + $day + $space + "(" + $year + "|" + $time + ")"
$match = $record -match $regex

Write-host $match
```

Вот таким методом выводится только True или False. Как мне из всей строки вывести найденное значение из сроки?

Answer (score 0):

вам нужно потом вывести резульатта командой  `$matches[0]`

вот другой способ:

```
PS C:\Users\> [regex]::match("OU=MTL1,OU=CORP,DC=FX,DC=LAB", "(?<=(^OU=))\w*(?=(,))").Groups[0].Value
MTL1
PS C:\Users\> 'OU=MTL1,OU=CORP,DC=FX,DC=LAB' -match '(?<=(^OU=))\w*(?=(,))'
True
PS C:\Users\> $matches[0]
MTL1
```

Answer (score -1):

Выдаст первое совпадение:

```
$record -match $regex |% {$matches[0]}
```

А вообще переменная `$matches` будет содержать массив всех совпадений.